# Time format control (":" or ".")

Tags: python, time

I have time column.

```
  Time
17:30:00
17:30:00    
17:30:00
17:30:00
17:30:00
```

Even though my time format is as above, there is also 17.30 in the data we receive. I can't check one by one as there are too many rows.

```
df[df["TIME"].str.contains('.',na=False)]
```

I wrote this code to check if it exists but it didn't work. How can I check and fix this situation?

Comment: How do you know it didn't work? What is `df`? Your time data doesn't have `17.30` in it. See how to create a [mcve], and [edit] the question.

Comment: @PeterWood I did not add other columns because they have nothing to do with this problem. The data I added is also an example of the time format that should be. When I run it, I can understand that it does not work with the result of 17:30:00.

Comment: What do you mean "it does not work"? [edit] the question.